# Read XML string in SQL and Dynamically select value from XMl string

Tags: sql, xml

I have One table "tblXMLData" with One column "coreData".

I am inserting XML string in this table.

I want to read this xml and insert record into another table.

When i write bellow code it is working fine,

```
    Declare @xmlRec xml
    Select TOP 1 @xmlRec = coreData FROM tblXMLData 

SELECT 
        tmpTable.col.query ('FName').value('.','varchar(50)') AS FName,
        tmpTable.col.query ('LName').value('.','varchar(50)') AS LName,
        tmpTable.col.query ('Mobile').value('.','varchar(50)') AS Mobile
FROM @xmlRec.nodes('data/data') AS tmpTable(col)
```

But I want to create select statement Dynamically. Like I am read column name from another table and creating dynamic select statement.

When i execute that statement it will not work because "@xmlRec.nodes" is giving error.

I want to create dynamic Query and insert selected record into another table.

Please help....

Comment: What do you mean by *dynamically* here "I want to create select statement Dynamically" ?